# Jquery : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'decode' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, base64

i am trying to use the btoa as see in below JSfiddle
Input

```
<input type="text" id="input" />
<button id="decode">Decode</button>

<p id="output"></p>
```

JS

```
$("#decode").click(function() {
    var getval = $("#input").val();
    var result = $.base64.decode(getval)
  $("p").text(result);
});
```

Reference Link : [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/onigetoc/g0y8qr9a)

it works on JSfiddle but when i try to add it to my code it on localhost it gives me below error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'decode' of undefined

can someone help me pls to sort the issue

Comment: What version of Jquery are u using ?

Comment: The errors in the title and the question imply two different problems

Comment: You've mentioned two different error messages but shared a code that doesn't exhibit none of them so I'm not sure how this can be answered. I can't find `jQuery.base64` in jQuery documentation, is it a builtin feature or a third-party plugin?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález It's a plugin: https://rawgit.com/carlo/jquery-base64/master/jquery.base64.min.js

Comment: The [example](https://jsfiddle.net/onigetoc/g0y8qr9a) works -> Please add a [mcve] _in the question itself_ that shows the actual problem.

Comment: i was trying 2 different scrips side by side by mistake copied the wrong message to the title

Comment: In that case the error means you haven't included the `$.base64` library in your page correctly.